# Wrong text changed listener invoked for custom view

Tags: android

In my android app I created a custom view named "IntSpinner". I created a xml in res/layout and a Java class extending GridLayout. My IntSpinner contains an EditText and a method to set a TextChangedListener/TextWatcher to this EditText.

I added two IntSpinners (S1 and S2) to my activity and added own TextChangedListeners to both of them (L1->S1, L2->S2).
The Problem: When the text of S1 is changed L2 is invoked.

I guess it is a id conflict, because I set the id of the EditText in the layout file, so the EditTexts of both spinners have the same ID. But as you can see in the code below, I use View.findViewById instead of AppCompatActivity.findViewById to get the EditText of the correct IntSpinner. And via debugging I can see that in this line the correct EditText is returned.

So why is the wrong listener invoked?

minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 16
Run on real device (Android 4.1.2)

Edit: added a SSCCE. When you make a configuration change (e.g. switch display from portrait to landscape) the spinner value is not correct.

TestSpinner class:

```
public class TestSpinner extends GridLayout {

    private EditText input;

    public TestSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public TestSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrSet) {
        super(context, attrSet);
        init(context);
    }

    public TestSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrSet, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrSet, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(final Context context) {
        View spinner = View.inflate(context, R.layout.test_spinner, this);
        input = spinner.findViewById(R.id.spinner_input);
    }

    public void addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher) {
        input.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    }

    public String getValue() {
        String value = input.getText().toString();
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        input.setText(value);
    }
}
```

TestSpinner layout

```
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:columnCount="1"
    android:rowCount="1">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/spinner_input"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:width="60dp"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_input"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="number" />

</GridLayout>
```

Activity class:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {

        String value1 = "1";
        String value2 = "2";
    }

    private MyViewModel viewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        TestSpinner spinner1 = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        TestSpinner spinner2 = findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
        spinner1.setValue(viewModel.value1);
        spinner2.setValue(viewModel.value2);

        spinner1.addTextChangedListener((MyTextListener) editable -> viewModel.value1 = spinner1.getValue());
        spinner2.addTextChangedListener((MyTextListener) editable -> viewModel.value2 = spinner2.getValue());
    }
}
```

Activity layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="enceladus.doko.app.activities.TestActivity">

    <enceladus.doko.app.views.TestSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <enceladus.doko.app.views.TestSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MyTextListener is a functional inferface that extends TextWatcher

Comment: Can you add the codes for activities? (Just the part that is setting/using the textWatcher)

Comment: added the code for the activity. I'm new to android development. Is there a general problem when there are views with the same id? Debugged the IntSpinner class. When I call editText.getText().toString() it returns the text of the other spinners text! I will try to write a small example code to show it.

Comment: I have added a SSCCE to demonstate the problem. I found out that after a configuration change (switch display to landscape mode) the problem occurs.